# Save High Resolution PNG with included Image in Chart Using d3.js on ObservableHQ.com

Tags: d3.js, observablehq

When creating a chart with D3.js, I can include an external image using :

```
svg.append("svg:image").attr("x", 100).attr("y", 100).attr(
"xlink:href",
"https://my-url.com/image.svg"
);
```

But when I try to save the chart as a PNG using a modified version of [this code](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/saving-svg) (for high resolution), the image doesn't show up in the PNG.

I've made a [test notebook here](https://observablehq.com/@7722371e7ecac8bd/save-high-resolution-png-with-imported-image) where you can try yourself.

I've been trying to fetch the image differently and transform it into a svg node, but I could not succeed in parsing the result properly. Any help is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little hacky, but it might work for you: https://observablehq.com/@shan/save-high-resolution-png-with-imported-image

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For those unfamiliar with Observable, it has a "compare fork to original" function that highlight Shan's changes: https://observablehq.com/compare/7e721b577160081f...d382320bb1355163